# Laravel php array for dynamic labels with graph consoletvs/charts:4

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, graph

I have a strange error when i try to create a graph with consoletvs/charts:4.* class

I run a mysql query and I want to generate a graph from my results. So far so good, except for the labels.

I'll show the code so you can see what I mean

```
$povprecje_all_24h=collect($query_povprecje_all_24h)->all();
    $data_24 = '';
    $mac_24 = array();
    foreach ($povprecje_all_24h as $povp24) {
                $data_24 = $data_24.(round(abs($povp24->PercentageDayPr - $povp24->PercentageAllPr)/$povp24->PercentageAllPr*100, 2) + round(abs($povp24->PercentageDaySt-$povp24->PercentageAllSt)/$povp24->PercentageAllSt*100, 2)).',';
                $krava=Cow::find($povp24->cowid);
                $mac_24[] = $krava->cow_name.' - '.$povp24->mac;
            }

    //$graph_bar_numb = count($mac_24); // so far so good... than i create a new chart
    $chart_24 = Charts::multi('bar', 'chartjs')
            ->responsive(false)
            ->dimensions(0, 500)
            ->colors(['#ca8585', '#00ff00', '#0000ff'])
            ->labels([$mac_24[0], $mac_24[1], $mac_24[2], $mac_24[3], $mac_24[4], $mac_24[5], $mac_24[6]])
            //->labels([$mac_24])
            //->$labels
            //->labels(['24866c07', '5009e02', '7f590a95', '948d06a0', '9c09c191', 'c00600be', 'f64bbed6'])
            ->dataset('Potrebuje pozornost', [$data_24]);
```

So when I insert the code ->Labels([$mac_24[0], $mac_24[1], $mac_24[2], $mac_24[3]) the bar graphs are working ...

When I insert the the labels manualy it is also working fine
like this: ->labels(['24866c07', '5009e02', '7f590a95', '948d06a0', '9c09c191', 'c00600be', 'f64bbed6'])

but when I do ->labels([$mac_24]) I get an error

> FatalErrorException in 59c3c83c254042cb2d7aaa267eb1e6bcbdcf976b.php line 0:
>   Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught ErrorException: Array to string conversion (View: /var/www/XXX/vendor/consoletvs/charts/resources/views/chartjs/multi/bar.blade.php)

I want to generate the labels dynamicaly so if I have 5 values in the array I want the graph to have 5 columns.

The code for the labels would be:

```
->Labels([$mac_24[0], $mac_24[1], $mac_24[2], $mac_24[3], $mac_24[4])
```

or when I have 2 values the code would be:

```
->Labels([$mac_24[0], $mac_24[1])
```

How can I do that?

Comment: if you do `->Labels([$mac_24])` or `->Labels($mac_24)` works?

Comment: ->Labels([$mac_24]) gives me the error 1/1
FatalErrorException in 59c3c83c254042cb2d7aaa267eb1e6bcbdcf976b.php line 0:
Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught ErrorException: Array to string conversion

Comment: Hey it looks like ->Labels($mac_24) is working fine!! Thank you thank you very much.

Comment: good to know :)